# Find an element in a BST Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am rewriting a search-for-an-element function in BST on my own, however I encountered this error which I'm not certain of what it means (error occured on the line of x (Empty) = False)

```
 Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = Tree a
 When generalising the type(s) for `searchTree'
```

Here is what I've come up with:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
                    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)


searchTree :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Bool
searchTree x (Empty) = False
searchTree x (Node left y right)
    |y == x = True
    |y > x = searchTree x left
    |y < x = searchTree x right
```

Comment: Your code does give me an error (because `left` and `y` should be swapped in the pattern of the second equation), but not the one you describe...

Comment: True, I tried it and error went away. Why can't it be "left y right" ?

Comment: @Walle Because the signature of the `Node` constructor states `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`. Therefore, the first item is the element, the next two are the subtrees.

Answer (score 4):

You have `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`, but pattern-match it as `(Node left y right)`. This infers the following types: `left :: a; y, right :: Tree a`. Then you compare `y :: Tree a` to `x :: a` - that forces them to have the same type, which is only possible if `Tree a` is the same type as `a`. That's an impossible<sup>1</sup>, infinite type, so GHC complains.

The solution is to fix your pattern match: it should be `(Node y left right)`, to match the data constructor.

<sup>1</sup> It's a theoretically possible type, just not a very useful one. `a ~ Tree a` can hold, but only if `a ~ Tree (Tree (Tree (Tree (Tree ...))))`.

Comment: I think there are some recent changes to how GHC treats infinite types. But it doesn't really matter: there's no requirement that every compiler give an identical error message for code that is wrong.

Comment: Agreed. I was just curious as to why we are getting different error messages.

Comment: Don't most (all?) type theories lack a notion of infinite types, just as they lack a notion of infinite terms?